# data and file upload form using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, file-upload

I need help with uploading data (dealer name, make, model etc) and multiple files (images & videos) to a folder and then the paths to a database.

I have the code which seems perfect because I am not getting any errors, but nothing is being sent to the database or the folder.

**upload.php**

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'mbiti', 'vaws');

//check connection
//if (!$link) {

//  die('Connect Error(' .mysqli-connect_errno(). ')'
//                  .mysqli-connect_errno());


//}

//escape variables for added security
//these field are entered by user using the form
$dealer_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['dealer_name']);
$phone_number = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['phone_number']);
$advert_title = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['advert_title']);
$make = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['make']);
$model = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['model']);
$type = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['type']);
$year = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['year']);
$price = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['price']);
$condition_ = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['condition_']);

$query2="INSERT into advert('dealer_name' , 'phone_number' , 'advert_title' , 'make' , 'model' , 'type' , 'year' , 'price' , 'condition_') VALUES ('$dealer_name' , '$phone_number' , '$advert_title' , '$make' , '$model' , '$type' , '$year' , '$price' , '$condition_')";
mysqli_query($con, $query2);    


if(isset($_FILES['files'])){
    $errors= array();
    foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
        $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
        $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];  
        if($file_size > 20971520){
            $errors[]='File size must be less than 20 MB';
        }   

        $query="INSERT into media (`FILE_NAME`,`FILE_SIZE`,`FILE_TYPE`) VALUES('$file_name','$file_size','$file_type')";


        $desired_dir="user_data";

        if(empty($errors)==true){
            if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
                mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);        // Create directory if it does not exist
            }
            if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false){
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"user_data/".$file_name);
            }else{                                  //rename the file if another one exist
                $new_dir="user_data/".$file_name.time();
                 rename($file_tmp,$new_dir) ;               
            }
            mysqli_query($con, $query); 
        }else{
                print_r($errors);
        }
    }
    if(empty($error)){
        echo "Success";
    }
}

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: Not the answer to your question, but you could cut down your code vastly by doing all that variable assignment in a loop.

Comment: @Utkanos, I am new to php as you have probably noticed. Can you help with that? Thanks

Comment: Sure - http://pastebin.com/1s2YL60E

Comment: @Utkanos thanks for the help, will implement it.